# How to trim a stream from an rtsp camera with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, raspberry-pi, streaming, v4l2

I need to crop the image of a stream coming from a camera on a **Raspberry pi**.

The camera is placed in a door peephole and I need to crop and enlarge the area of interest to see it full screen.

[image]

I have only been using Linux for a short time and it is very difficult for me to continue advancing in this regard. Here is the way I stream from my **Raspberry pi**:

I am using **v4l2rtspserver** to stream my camera image on my home network:

```
v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0
```

Then in tvheadend I can see the broadcast on my TV using **ffmpeg** (as if it were a TV channel):

```
pipe:///usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel fatal -i rtsp://192.168.1.56:8555/unicast -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts -mpegts_service_type 0x01 pipe:1
```

I have tried to crop the image in this way, but it does absolutely nothing, maybe I am placing it wrong (I don't know how to do it).

```
pipe:///usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel fatal -i rtsp://192.168.1.56:8555/unicast -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts -mpegts_service_type 0x01 pipe:1 -vf "crop=100:100:12:34"
```

Can you help me?

Comment: **1.** You **can't** use `-vf "crop=100:100:12:34"` together `-vcodec copy`. Try replacing `-vcodec copy` with `-vcodec libx264 -crf 17`. **2.** Place `-vf "crop=100:100:12:34"` right after `rtsp://192.168.1.56:8555/unicast`. **3.** Check if the camera supports ROI cropping (at the source).

Comment: Thank you very much Rotem, it has worked like a charm for me. Could you post an answer to consider it valid? In case anyone needs help on this matter.

Comment: I don't think that re-encoding is good solution. What happen if you use `v4l2rtspserver -H 480 -W 640 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0` ? Are you getting the center or is it not working?

Comment: I understand you, although that would be worth it. But where tvheadend is running (my server) cpu usage goes up by 30%. Maybe it's better to cut from the raspberry. The problem is that the image of the peephole of my door is smaller and appears below the screen, that is, it is not in the center, that is why I have to crop the image. How could I do it before the transmission? Thank you Rotem

Comment: Doing re-encoding in the Raspberry Pi my not be a good idea, because the hardware may be to weak for re-encoding the video (in Raspberry Pi 4 there is hardware acceleration for H.264 encoding and decoding, but I don't know how difficult is the setup). If your camera doesn't support ROI cropping (that is not at the center), it is probably the best to crop and re-encode in the PC. For reducing CPU usage you may try other codecs like `mjpeg`, and may try hardware acceleration - using `h264_qsv` codec instead of `libx264`.

Comment: Thank you very much Rotem. I would like to try those codecs but I don't know how to implement it in my code, could you tell me how or give me a guide? Thank you !!